# Why do I have to include "/dist" in library import

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, npm, vite

I am writing a react component library with vite as my build tool.

I've compiled the project and deployed it to the npm registry. When I am importing it from my client app, I have to include "/dist" in the import.

From the client app, importing like below...

```
import { Tuple } from 'tuple-ui';
```

...results in the error below in vscode:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'tuple-ui'. '/arbitrary/path/tuple/dist/tuple.umd.js' implicitly has an 'any' type. Try `npm i --save-dev @types/tuple-ui` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'tuple-ui';`ts(7016)
```

However, when I include "dist" in the import...

```
import { Tuple } from 'tuple-ui/dist';
```

...The error goes away.

Below is my vite.config.ts for the component library:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import dts from 'vite-plugin-dts';
import * as path from 'path';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react(),
    dts({
      insertTypesEntry: true,
    }),
  ],
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/lib/index.ts'),
      name: 'tuple',
      fileName: 'tuple'
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ['react', 'react-dom'],
      output: {
        globals: {
          react: 'React',
          'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
        }
      }
    }
  },
})
```

And here is the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "tuple-ui",
  "version": "0.0.10",
  "license": "MIT",
  "author": "budl",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tscv": "tsc --version",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook",
    "chromatic": "npx chromatic --project-token=e183f70dfe01"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "chromatic": "^6.9.0",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.6",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.5.9",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.5.9",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^6.5.9",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.5.9",
    "@storybook/builder-vite": "^0.1.38",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.5.9",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.0.13",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^1.3.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4",
    "vite": "^2.9.9",
    "vite-plugin-dts": "^0.9.10"
  },
  "readme": "ERROR: No README data found!",
  "type": "module",
  "files": [ "dist" ],
  "main": "./dist/tuple.umd.js",
  "module": "./dist/tuple.es.js",
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": "./dist/tuple.es.js",
      "require": "./dist/tuple.umd.js"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is `from 'tuple-ui/dist';` in their docs? It's not really a satisfying answer, but my guess is its just an oversight on the developers' part. Maybe some popular modules that depend on it use /dist as an entry point? Just another guess.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because you developed your library using typescript and you don't have module declarations in your library for typescript files, even you can see how the error is suggesting to you to run this command in order to install the library's types:

```
npm i --save-dev @types/tuple-ui
```

So in this case you have two options:

1- Run the suggested command and see if it fixes your problem.

2- Write your library declaration files. (Here you can get more documentation about it: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html)

The error goes away when you import the /dist directory because in this directory you have your typescript files transpiled to javascript.

Comment: I thought importing and using dts({...}) in the vite.config.ts file was supposed to auto-generate all the type information for me. What does it do if not generate the type information?

Comment: @BudLinville can you show me your dts config?

Comment: It's alright. I just figured out the answer. I appreciate your help though!

Comment: Oh, perfect! :)

Comment: @BudLinville Could you share the answer?

Comment: @Audiopolis I'm the other answerer. I posted my solution above

Comment: @Audiopolis Do you have the dts stuff in your vite.config.ts file? Moreover, can you confirm your types files (foobar.d.ts) were generated?

Comment: Oh, I somehow missed that. I do already have `types` in `package.json` (same path as yours), and the file is indeed generated in `src` (which ends up in `dist/src/index.d.ts`). I'm not sure if that's what I want. The only contents of that file is an `export * as myModule from "./myModule"` and a `//# sourceMappingURL=index.d.ts.map`. Additionally, one `d.ts` file is created per `.ts` file in each subdirectory containing TS files.

Comment: @Audiopolis See if my edits to my answer help. Also start commenting there as that is the more relevant thread.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else that has screwed this up, the solution was to add a **types** field in **package.json** that pointed to the types file generated by **dts**

[image]

## Edit 1

To answer Audioplis's comment:

You need to define your exports for your library. I did this in `src/lib/index.ts`. See below line in my `vite.config.ts`:

```
...
entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/lib/index.ts'),
...
```

Then this is what my `src/lib/index.ts` looks like:

```
export { default as Tuple } from '../components/Tuple';
export { default as Page } from '../components/Page';
export { default as Bubble } from '../components/Bubble';

import lannister from 
'../components/Tuple/templates/lannister.module.css';
import baratheon from 
'../components/Tuple/templates/baratheon.module.css';
export const templates = {
    lannister,
    baratheon,
}

export { getUniqueId } from '../utils';
```

You can define whatever exports you want from your project. This includes any types you want to export as well.

Comment: I already have this, but still have the problem OP describes.