# Remove "/dist/src" from import path when consuming library

Tags: typescript, npm, vite, package.json, tsconfig

I'm using Vite to create a small library that I'm publishing privately to the NPM registry. I have gotten it to build and be importable, but when imported in a project that depends on this library, the import path looks like this: `import { example } from "@my-org/my-lib/dist/src/forms/utils"`

Notice the `/dist/src`. I would prefer if the import looked like this: `import { example } from "@my-org/my-lib/forms/utils"`, without the `/dist/src`.

I have tried changing `baseUrl` in `tsconfig.json`, but it seemed to only apply to files inside the `my-lib` project, not in the imports. It caused a lot of problems, and was generally a waste of time and a dead end (I could be wrong).

I have tried the answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74883393/why-do-i-have-to-include-dist-in-library-import), but neither one resolves the problem.

Here is my `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ESNext",
        "useDefineForClassFields": true,
        "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext"],
        "allowJs": false,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "strict": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "module": "ESNext",
        "moduleResolution": "bundler",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "noEmit": false,
        "jsx": "react-jsx",
        "declaration": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "declarationMap": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "@my-org/my-lib": ["src/index"]
        },
        "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types", "src/index.d.ts"],
        "allowImportingTsExtensions": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "composite": true,
        "outDir": "dist",
    },
    "files": [],
    "include": ["src/**/*"],
    "exclude": ["dist"],
    "references": [
        {
            "path": "./tsconfig.vite.json"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is my `package.json`:

```json
{
    "name": "@my-org/my-lib",
    "description": "Core functionality for My App",
    "main": "./dist/my-lib.umd.js",
    "author": "My Org",
    "license": "UNLICENSED",
    "version": "1.0.0-alpha.22",
    "type": "module",
    "module": "./dist/my-lib.es.js",
    "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "tsc && vite build",
        "lint": "eslint . --ext ts,tsx,js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
        "lint:fix": "eslint . --ext ts,tsx,js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0 --fix",
        "format": "prettier --write \"**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,json,md,html,sass,yaml}\" --config ./.prettierrc",
        "preview": "vite preview",
        "prepare": "husky install",
    },
    "publishConfig": {
        "access": "restricted"
    },
    "dependencies": {},
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/react": "^18.2.15",
        "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.4.1",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.4.1",
        "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.3",
        "eslint": "^8.47.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.0.0",
        "eslint-plugin-jest": "^27.2.3",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.0.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.2",
        "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.3",
        "eslint-plugin-simple-import-sort": "^10.0.0",
        "husky": "^8.0.3",
        "jest": "^29.6.3",
        "prettier": "^3.0.2",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "typescript": "^5.2.2",
        "vite": "^4.4.5",
        "vite-plugin-dts": "^3.5.2",
        "vite-plugin-externalize-deps": "^0.7.0",
        "vite-plugin-linter": "^2.0.5",
        "vite-tsconfig-paths": "^4.2.0"
    },
    "peerDependencies": {
        "leaflet": "^1.9.0",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "react-redux": "^8.1.2"
    },
    "husky": {
        "hooks": {
            "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
        }
    },
    "lint-staged": {
        "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}": [
            "yarn eslint",
            "yarn format"
        ]
    },
    "files": [
        "dist"
    ],
    "exports": {
        ".": {
            "import": "./dist/my-lib.es.js",
            "require": "./dist/my-lib.umd.js"
        },
        "./forms": "./dist/forms"
    },
    "keywords": [
        "react",
        "geospacial",
        "map",
        "components"
    ],
    "homepage": "https://example.com",
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "git+https://github.com/my-org/my-lib.git"
    },
    "bugs": {
        "url": "https://github.com/my-org/my-lib/issues"
    }
}
```

The .ts files are transpiled into a `/dist/` directory. Because the transpiled files originated from a `src` directory, this is mirrored, so all files containing any code are located in `/dist/src`.

Essentially, what I want is this: While I the source files are located in a `src` directory, and those are transpiled into a `dist` directory, I want neither `dist` nor `src` in the path when importing stuff from this library I'm creating.

Comment: I guess it's baseUrl": ".", should be src

Comment: to remove dist as well you need package json exports ./\* ./dist/*

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not affect the final import path after the library has been published and consumed by another project.